# Prolog. I can't mix two lists

Tags: list, prolog

I want to mix two lists into one. For example, `[1,3,5]` and `[2,3,9]` would yield `[1,2,3,5,9]`.

I tried this:

```
mezclar( L1, L2, L3 ):-
  L1 = [Cab|Cola] ,
  L3 = [Cab,Cola2] ,
  mezclar(L2,Cola,Cola2) .
mezclar( L1, L2, L3 ):-
  L1=[] ,
  L3=L2 .
```

But I have 2 problems.

- The first problem are duplicated numbers
- The second one is that I'm putting lists into the list and I dont want to.

If I execute

```
mezclar( [1,3,5], [2,5,9], X ).
```

I get

```
X = [1, [2, [3, [5, [5|...]]]]]
```

Comment: mezclar(L1,L2,L3):-L1=[],L3=L2.
mezclar(L1,L2,L3):-L1=[Cab|Cola],mezclar(L2,Cola,Cola1),L3=[Cab|Cola1].

now i got the list ordered but i got the same issue with the duplicated numbers

Comment: Before adding each element to the new list, check whether it is already present. You can use append/3 to insert elements, and member/2 to check if they are already in the list

Comment: If you are using SWI-Prolog then see [ord_union/2 or ord_union/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/ordsets.pl)

Answer (score 0):

To mix two lists into one, with the resulting list being ordered and without duplicates, try:

```
mezclar(L1,L2,L3) :- append(L1,L2,L4), sort(L4,L3).
```

The query:

```
mezclar([1,3,5], [2,5,9], X).
```

will produce the result:

```
X = [1, 2, 3, 5, 9]
```

This example uses `sort/2`. Here is a link to the SWI documentation for `sort/2`:

http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/2

Answer (score 0):

Are input lists ***sorted***? If so you merge them pretty fast.

```
merge([], Xs, Xs).
merge([X|Xs], [], [X|Xs]).
merge([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [X|Zs]) :- X < Y, merge(Xs, [Y|Ys], Zs).
merge([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [Y|Zs]) :- X > Y, merge([X|Xs], Ys, Zs).
merge([X|Xs], [X|Ys], [X|Zs]) :- merge(Xs, Ys, Zs).
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your lists are *ordered*, then it would seem that you are looking at a straight merge. And that's simple:

```
merge( []     , []     , []       ) .  % merging two empty lists yields the empty list itself
merge( []     , [Y|Ys] , [Y|Ys]   ) .  % merging the empty list with a non-empty list yields the non-empty list 
merge( [X|Xs] , []     , [X|Xs]   ) .  % merging a non-empty list with the empty list yields the non-empty list
merge( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , [X,Y|Zs] ) :- % otherwise, when both lists are non-empty...
  X @= Y ,                             % - if X and Y compare as equal (in the standard order of terms)
  merge( Xs, Ys, Zs ) .                % - Take both X and Y and recurse down on the tail(s).
merge( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , [X|Zs] ) :-   % otherwise, when both lists are non-empty...
  X @< Y ,                             % - if X compares low to Y (in the standard order of terms)
  merge( Xs, [Y|Ys], Zs ) .            % - Take X and recurse down on the tail(s).
merge( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , [X|Zs] ) :-   % otherwise, when both lists are non-empty...
  X @> Y ,                             % - if X compares hight to Y (in the standard order of terms)
  merge( [X|Xs], Ys, Zs ) .            % - Take Y and recurse down on the tail(s).
```

The above will not eliminate duplicates from the set, nor will it unify any unbound variables. Merging `[1,3,5]` with `[1,3,5]` yields `[1,1,3,3,5,5]` as you would expect. If you want set-like semantics, you'll need to modify the last 3 clauses to use different comparision/unification operators.